# Can't add package name to Facebook developer console for login on Android

Tags: android, facebook-login

I would like to add android as a platform to the Facebook developer console.
But when I enter my package name the following error is displayed:

> One or more invalid package name(s). Make sure package names are
> associated with a valid Google Play store URL.

[image: error in Facebook developer console]

Does anyone knows what exactly is checked by the console?

My App is already in Play Store available but only for internal tests.

I checked my package name with the following url:

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={my-package-name}](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%7Bmy-package-name%7D)

With this link my app is displayed but as unreviewed.

**Please could someone tell me what could I do to add android to the Facebook developer console?**

Any tips or ideas are really appreciated.